# datetime.strptime doesn't work in PyQt4 QtGui.QWidget inherited class

Tags: python, pyqt4, strptime

For example I have this simple class:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
from datetime import datetime

print datetime.strptime('Wed, 06-Feb-2014 12:05:12', '%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')

class Application(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
      super(Application, self).__init__()
      print datetime.strptime('Wed, 06-Feb-2014 12:05:12', '%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')

def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Application()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I run it I have the following output:

```
2014-02-06 12:05:12
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vkPlayListSync.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()    
  File "vkPlayListSync.py", line 18, in main
    ex = Application()
  File "vkPlayListSync.py", line 12, in __init__
    print datetime.strptime('Wed, 06-Feb-2014 12:05:12', '%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data 'Wed, 06-Feb-2014 12:05:12' does not match format '%a, %d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S'
```

so the first line with `strptime`, but the second call form the class `__init()__` method throws error. I have not enough experience in Python and PyQt, so can't understand how to fix this. And I haven't found the answer here on stackoverflow or in google.

Comment: You copied your code and it's running fine here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QApplication` startup is altering your locale such that `'Wed, 06-Feb-2014 12:05:12'` is no longer a valid date (i.e. the weekday and month names are in another language).  Try running your application with `LC_ALL="C"`.