# datetime's strptime returns Value Error when using the Qt GUI module

Tags: python, qt, datetime, jupyter, strptime

I am trying to run a Jupyter notebook that uses the Qt GUI module.
I just realized that this module prevents datetime's `strptime` from working properly.

The following snippet returns datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0), just as expected:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('2000 Jan 01 00:00:0.000', '%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

But calling the Qt GUI module *before* these two lines throws a 'does not match format error':

```
%gui qt
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('2000 Jan 01 00:00:0.000', '%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

This is the error message that I am getting:

> ValueError: time data '2000 Jan 01 00:00:0.000' does not match format
> '%Y %b %d %H:%M:%S.%f'

Any idea how to circumvent this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14684513/datetime-strptime-doesnt-work-in-pyqt4-qtgui-qwidget-inherited-class and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39658719/conflict-between-pyqt5-and-datetime-datetime-strptime

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Cubix48! This looks like a promising lead. I have no idea where to change the `LC_ALL="C"` parameter as suggested in the answer but I will give it a shot.

Comment: Huzzah! The second post that you suggested did the trick (`import locale` followed by `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "en_GB.utf8")`). Thanks a lot!